# Laziness of spark pipline

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a question about the laziness of **Apache Spark** pipelines. I do understand spark transformations and actions.

Let's take an example:

The following snippet is a transformation that returns an RDD of all filenames in a folder.

```
val filenames = sc.wholeTextFiles("pathToDirectory").map( _ match { case (filename, content) =>  filename })
```

If I execute the action :

```
filenames.count
```

spark is executing all the defined transformations including loading the 'filename' RDD and the 'content' RDD into memory even if 'content' is not used

Is there a better way to write spark transformations such as: not used code (like 'content' RDD in the previous example) is not evaluated while executing actions?

Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: If you don't care about file content, why don't you use lower Hadoop API to count files in the directory?

Comment: It is not about counting. the count was just an example to trigger an action.